# How to send Notification Message with gcm-server.jar

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the gcm-server.jar to send gcm Messages from Server because its easy to use. (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmserverjar.htm).
Messages are sent with this code. This works fine:

```
Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", message).build();
Sender sender = new Sender();
Result result = sender.send(msg, token, 5);
...
```

How can I send a GCM Message with Notification Payload like in this JSON:

```
 {"to":"token" ,
 "notification":{
 "sound":"default",
 "badge":"1",
 "title":"this is the title",
 "body":"this is the body"}}
```

Comment: Hi SmilingM, Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Hi, no. Best way is to create the json request manually. Seems like there are no good libraries for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server set up where you parse these messages in JSON format so that GCM can process it accordingly.

Usually this depends on what server technology you are using. Also, you might want to check the validity of the library you referenced as GCM framework has been updated substantially.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)'s a good place to start.
And another good tutorial [here](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/). (although this one is older too but gives you understanding of server side implementation)

Hope this helps!